# Выбор между enum и final class для хранения опций

Tags: java, ооп

Разрабатываю приложение на Java 8, в котором мне необходимо использовать некие настройки. Настройки могут быть разными, объединяет их сейчас то, что есть некоторое представление настройки (сейчас это - элемент перечисления), и ключ и значение настройки. Настройки планируется добавлять в `ArrayList`.

Сейчас передо мной встал выбор - использовать ли перечисление, реализующее общий интерфейс, для хранения настроек, или же попробовать воспользоваться `final class`.

Конкретно Java я только начинаю всерьёз заниматься, поэтому вопрос может быть глуповат, но поиск в Сети на русском и английском языках не дал мне ясности.

Привожу пример (абстрактный), как реализовано сейчас:

```
public interface Option {
    public String getKey();
    public String getValue();
}

public enum Option1 implements Option {
    OPTION1_VALUE_1("one"),
    OPTION1_VALUE_2("two");
    private final String key;
    private final String value;
    Option1(String val) {
        this.key = "key1";
        this.value = val;
    }
    @Override
    public String getKey() {
        return this.key;
    }
    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}

public enum Option2 implements Option {
    OPTION2_VALUE_1("aaa"),
    OPTION2_VALUE_2("bbb");
    private final String key;
    private final String value;
    Option2(String val) {
        this.key = "key2";
        this.value = val;
    }
    @Override
    public String getKey() {
        return this.key;
    }
    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

Затем я планирую использовать эти "опции" как-то так:

```
List<Option> options = new ArrayList<Option>;
options.add(Option1.OPTION1_VALUE_1);
options.add(Option2.OPTION2_VALUE_1);
options.add(Option2.OPTION2_VALUE_2);
// А теперь, например, обходим список и выводим value
for (Option opt : options) {
    System.out.println(opt.getValue());
}
```

Вот, собственно, для этих целей я и использую интерфейс.

В данной реализации мне (а как показал поиск - и многим другим вопрошающим) не нравится необходимость в каждом enum'е переопределять функции `getKey()` и `getValue()`. Наследовать `enum` от класса Java не позволяет.

Гугление привело меня к статье "[Constant interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_interface)" в Википедии, откуда я почерпнул идею реализовать подобное поведение через `final class`.

Реализацию я вижу примерно так:

```
public class Option {
    protected final String key;
    public getKey() {
        return this.key;
    }
}

public final class Option1 extends Option {
    Option() {
        this.key = "key1";
    }
    public static final String OPTION1_VALUE_1 = "one";
    public static final String OPTION1_VALUE_2 = "two";
}

public final class Option2 extends Option {
    Option() {
        this.key = "key2";
    }
    public static final String OPTION2_VALUE_1 = "aaa";
    public static final String OPTION2_VALUE_2 = "bbb";
}
```

Код накидывал прямо здесь, без отладки, лишь чтобы передать идею. Соответственно, при такой реализации я отказываюсь от метода `getValue()` и получаю значение через сам член класса.

Собственно, вопросы:

1. Можно ли всё-таки как-то избежать необходимости переопределения
   `getKey()` и `getValue()` в первом варианте реализации (через
   enum'ы)?
2. Насколько вообще адекватна первая реализация, с позиции более
   опытных разработчиков?
3. Жизнеспособна ли идея второй реализации (через `final class`)? Лучше
   ли она, чем использование enum'ов? Лично мне кажется для этих целей
   более правильно использовать перечисление, но из-за недостатка опыта
   я сильно сомневаюсь в таком решении.

Comment: Если набор элементов определён раз и навсегда используйте enum, Пусть в каждом надо переопределить чего-то там, зато сразу ясно что это enum, и ясно что от него ожидать (конечный постоянный набор опций). Ни при каких ошибках не могут возникнуть лишние экземпляры опций.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Первую реализацию можно заменить на более удачную. В Enum можно определять свои конструкторы и методы. Тогда нет необходимости создавать интерфейс и т.п.. Мне кажется это будет наиболее удачным вариантом решения.

```
public enum Option {
    OPTION_1("key 1", "value 1"),
    OPTION_2("key 2", "value 2");

    private String key;
    private String value;

    Option(String key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

По поводу использования. Если необходимо пройтись по всем опциям, то есть стандартный метод `values()`:

```
for (Option op : Option.values()) {
  System.out.println(op.getKey() + " - " + op.getValue());
}
```

Если необходимо оперировать только частью опций, то используйте [EnumSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html), который предоставляет компактную и быструю структуру данных за счет внутренней реализации в виде битового вектора.

Comment: Я добавил в первое сообщение пример того, как примерно я хочу использовать (точнее, уже использую) опции, иллюстрирующий, зачем мне интерфейс. Честно говоря, не совсем понял Ваш ответ, не могли бы Вы его немного пояснить? По сути, у меня уже есть конструктор в enum'е (без него я value и не заполнил бы), и геттеры для key и value... Не улавливаю существенных отличий :-(

Comment: @SergeyPopov Дополнил ответ. Единственное я не понял зачем вам несколько значений для одного параметра. Если это требуется, то используйте список внутри enum.

Comment: Возможно, иногда мне сложно объяснить свои мысли :) Смотрите. У меня есть некий класс, в который я добавляю настройки - сейчас это язык и настройка страницы. Всё это я храню в члене класса типа ArrayList. И, соответственно, у меня отдельные enum'ы для языка и настройки страницы, наследующие общий интерфейс. Причём языков можно добавить несколько (или не одного), а настройку страницы только одну... Оба вида опций хранят key (ключ, который передаётся внешнему приложению) и value (значение для этого ключа).

Comment: Если необходимо хранить несколько языков, то создайте простое перечисление с этими языками `public enum Language { RU, EN; }`. Далее создайте класс `PageSettings`, в качестве полей этого класса используйте вышепредставленный `Option` (единичное поле) и `EnumSet`, состоящий из значений перечисления `Language`. В этом классе соответственно определите методы добавления/удаления языков, изменения поля типа `Option` и прочую логику.

Comment: Погуглил/почитал про EnumSet, интересно, спасибо. К сожалению, или я не понимаю до конца Вашего ответа (туплю), или я плохо доношу свои мысли. Перечисление я хочу хранить вне класса, использующего его, т.к. предполагается повторное использование кода, то есть я не могу заранее знать, какие именно опции нужно будет добавить. Хотел реализовать у класса метод `addOption()`, принимающий любую из опций и добавляющий её в List. А EnumSet, как я понимаю, не очень удобно формировать вот так вот "на лету"...

Comment: Так я вам и предлагаю создать класс PageSettings с настройками для единичной страницы. А уже экземпляры этого класса вы можете хранить в списке, где угодно. Либо если есть класс Page, то он может хранить эти настройки.

Comment: Понял Вас, спасибо большое за помощь и терпение :)

Comment: @SergeyPopov если список опций планируется пополнять по ходу работы программы, то используйте классы. Enum, как я раньше говорил только для наборов неизменных. Ну вы конечно можете их менять, только с последующей установкой новой версии программы. А классы в качестве пополняемых по необходимости "enum-ов" используются. И даже в библиотеках, которые обеспечивают так сказать инфраструктуру всего комплекса (например в undertow - web-сервере, используемом в Weildfly). Ничего криминального в этом нет.

Comment: @banme Список опций будет не изменяемый (или изменяемый только в новых версиях), т.к. по сути это параметры, с которыми будет вызываться внешняя программа.